I can't deploy my contract on Remix IDE
I'm trying to write my first smart contract but when I try to deploy it I get this:

This contract may be abstract, it may not implement an abstract
parent's methods completely or it may not invoke an inherited
contract's constructor correctly.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could take a look at my code. Thanks so much in advance. This is my code:
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function swapExactETHForTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
}

contract TokenSniper {
    address public owner;
    IUniswapV2Router public uniswapRouter;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _uniswapRouter) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router(_uniswapRouter);
    }

function snipeToken(
    address _tokenAddress,
    uint amountOutMin,
    uint deadline
) external payable onlyOwner {
    // Declare and initialize the path array locally
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[1] = _tokenAddress;

    // Execute the token swap
    require(msg.value >= amountOutMin, "Not enough ETH sent");
    
    uniswapRouter.swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(
        amountOutMin,
        path,
        address(this), // Sending tokens to this contract
        deadline
    );
}


function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        // Withdraw contract's own balance to the owner
        payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

receive() external payable {}
}


Since, the IUniswapV2Router interface is in the same file, so it's selected by default in the dropdown of the CONTRACT in the Deploy & run transactions tab.

So, you've to select the TokenSniper contract from the dropdown before clicking on Deploy button.

Now, you can simply pass the UniswapV2Router contract address, which you can find in the Uniswap docs, depending on the network where you're deploying your TokenSniper contract, and then click on Deploy.

